# How can I randomize a CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I am relatively new to R, and I am trying to figure out how to take a csv that contains a list of words and randomize it. I need to create a map of objects and I want to figure out how to randomly populate the map with my list, or to simply randomize the list so I can populate the map randomly. What command can I use to do this?

Comment: If you're reading the csv file into R as a data frame (let's say your data frame is called `dat`), then you can randomize the row order as follows: `dat = dat[sample(1:nrow(dat)), ]`

Comment: Do you want to choose rows at random? If so use `help("sample")` to choose row numbers, say, `inx` and then `rnd <- dat[inx, ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sample()` function, to shuffles rows in CSV file (`data.frame`) or shuffling a `vector` of objects

**Input**

If input CSV file has multiple rows

```
Test <- read.table("MapTest.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
Test
#       V1    V2     V3
# 1 Heaven   Air Flower
# 2  Earth  Lily   Jazz
# 3   Hell Dance Tennis
# 4  Sweet  Sour Bitter

dim(Test)
# [1] 4 3
```

**Shuffling rows**

Running it multiple times, shuffles differently every time

```
  Test[sample(1:nrow(Test)),]
  #       V1    V2     V3
  # 2  Earth  Lily   Jazz
  # 4  Sweet  Sour Bitter
  # 3   Hell Dance Tennis
  # 1 Heaven   Air Flower

  Test[sample(1:nrow(Test)),]
  #       V1    V2     V3
  # 3   Hell Dance Tennis
  # 1 Heaven   Air Flower
  # 2  Earth  Lily   Jazz
  # 4  Sweet  Sour Bitter
```

**Selecting 2 rows after shuffling**

Selecting 2 rows after shuffling number of rows in the CSV file. Running it multiple times will result in different 2 rows each time.

```
  Test[sample(1:nrow(Test), 2),]
  #       V1   V2     V3
  # 4  Sweet Sour Bitter
  # 1 Heaven  Air Flower

  Test[sample(1:nrow(Test), 2),]
  #      V1    V2     V3
  # 4 Sweet  Sour Bitter
  # 3  Hell Dance Tennis
```

**Shuffling objects of each row in Multiple row CSV file**

```
  lapply(1:nrow(Test), function(x) sample(Test[x,]))
  # [[1]]
  #       V1     V3  V2
  # 1 Heaven Flower Air
  # 
  # [[2]]
  #     V3   V2    V1
  # 2 Jazz Lily Earth
  # 
  # [[3]]
  #      V2     V3   V1
  # 3 Dance Tennis Hell
  # 
  # [[4]]
  #       V3    V1   V2
  # 4 Bitter Sweet Sour
```

---

---

**Input**

If Input has 1 row: Objects comma separated

```
  Test <- read.table("MapTest.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
  dim(Test)
  # [1]  1 12
  Test
  #       V1  V2     V3    V4   V5   V6   V7    V8     V9   V10  V11    V12
  # 1 Heaven Air Flower Earth Lily Jazz Hell Dance Tennis Sweet Sour Bitter
```

**Shuffling objects of a CSV file with 1 row**

It will results different if ran multiple times.

```
  sample(Test)
  #     V5    V4     V1   V6    V8     V9  V2   V10    V12  V11   V7     V3
  # 1 Lily Earth Heaven Jazz Dance Tennis Air Sweet Bitter Sour Hell Flower

  sample(Test)
  #      V4   V7     V1    V12     V3  V11    V8   V5   V10     V9   V6  V2
  # 1 Earth Hell Heaven Bitter Flower Sour Dance Lily Sweet Tennis Jazz Air
```

---

---

**If No Input CSV File**

Create a vector of objects in R

```
  Map_vec <- c("Hell","Heaven","Flower","Water","Air","Sky")
  Map_vec
  # [1] "Hell"   "Heaven" "Flower" "Water"  "Air"    "Sky"   

  length(Map_vec)
  # [1] 6
```

**Shuffling Vector**

```
  sample(Map_vec)
  # [1] "Flower" "Sky"    "Heaven" "Air"    "Hell"   "Water" 

  sample(Map_vec)
  # [1] "Water"  "Heaven" "Sky"    "Hell"   "Air"    "Flower"
```

**Shuffling and selecting few from vector**

```
  sample(Map_vec, 3)
  # [1] "Heaven" "Sky"    "Hell"  

  sample(Map_vec, 3)
  # [1] "Heaven" "Sky"    "Air"
```